# Is there a way to find the value for the last day of each month in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe which gives me the daily quantity levels of various articles. I want to get a dataframe which gives me the quantity levels on the last day of every month of each article.

**OriginaL df:**

| item | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 23/09/21 | 2143 |
| bat | 21/09/2021 | 2444 |
| cola | 15/09/21 | 1512 |
| apple | 21/10/21 | 2906 |
| bat | 4/10/21 | 2730 |
| cola | 16/10/21 | 2449 |
| cola | 31/12/2021 | 0 |
| apple | 27/12/2021 | 1086 |
| bat | 25/12/2021 | 1186 |
| apple | 26/12/2021 | 1377 |

**Target df:**

| item | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cola | 31/12/2021 | 0 |
| apple | 27/12/2021 | 1086 |
| bat | 25/12/2021 | 1186 |

Is there any way to obtain it?

I tried group by item and date with tail() but it didn't work.

Comment: "I tried group by item and date with tail() but it didn't work." Show what you tried. [ask] [mre]

Comment: in the original data frame you have dates in Sep and Oct, while in the target df you have all in Dec. n your question you requested "the quantity levels on the last day of every month of each article", please clarify this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC need last values per years by [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.groupby(['item', pd.Grouper(freq='Y', key='Date')]).tail(1)
print (df)
    item       Date  Quantity
6   cola 2021-12-31         0
8    bat 2021-12-25      1186
9  apple 2021-12-26      1377
```

because per monhts output is different:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.groupby(['item', pd.Grouper(freq='m', key='Date')]).tail(1)
print (df)
    item       Date  Quantity
0  apple 2021-09-23      2143
1    bat 2021-09-21      2444
2   cola 2021-09-15      1512
3  apple 2021-10-21      2906
4    bat 2021-10-04      2730
5   cola 2021-10-16      2449
6   cola 2021-12-31         0
8    bat 2021-12-25      1186
9  apple 2021-12-26      1377
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael.
I was not aware of the pd.grouper
It works perfectly, I learnt something new